# Is it possible to create a Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Mod in Python?

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm  not the most comfortable person with C++, C#, or C, but I am good with Python.

I want to create like an utility mod for Minecraft (preferably Windows 10 Edition), and I just wondered if it would be possible in Python?

(I know this is kind of off-topic but I couldn't find a fitting place to ask this)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it isn't possible yet in Windows10 edition... But I found [this for Java version.](https://www.instructables.com/Python-coding-for-Minecraft/)